# Selenium xpath text() - simple selection seemingly not working

Tags: selenium, xpath

I use Selenium WebDriver 2.53.1 on Java, Chrome.

I find an element and save it in a WebElement variable named dropdownMenuList . here is its outerHTML, formatted.

```
<ul tabindex="-1" class="dropdownMenu apmurldropdownmenu thing menu" role="menu" aria-label="Menu region">
    <li class="menuitem apmurldropdownmenu" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
        <div class="thing text">CardNameWebpage</div>
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem apmurldropdownmenu" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
        <div class="thing text">CardNameWebpage</div>
    </li>
    <li class="menuitem apmurldropdownmenu" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
        <div class="thing text">CardNameWebpage</div>
    </li>
    <!-- react-text: 9 -->
    <!-- /react-text -->
</ul>
```

Then I search in it by xpath:

```
dropdownMenuList.findElement(By.xpath("*[text()='CardNameWebpage']"));
```

And I get a NoSuchElementException. But the HTML has all of three elements with this text. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put two slashes (`//`) before because elements which you are looking for are not on top level

```
"//*[text()='CardNameWebpage']"
```

To find descendant  element of current one  (paul tremberth is absolutely right :)),  add point at start of the xpath

```
".//*[text()='CardNameWebpage']"
```

Comment: If I use // it searches from the top of the document. I need to search from this element only.

Comment: Then try `.//*[text()='CardNameWebpage']` (relative location path)

Comment: I would replace `*` with `div` in this case to make it more specific... but that may just be me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edited: You need to change to, `//*[text()='value']` or `//*[contains(text(),'value')]`.

Comment: I think he meant either //*[text()='value'] or //*[contains(text(), 'value')] since you know it's a list item, you could replace "*" with "li" in both cases, and in the contains version, you could substitute "." for "text()"

Comment: If I use // it searches from the top of the document. I need to search from this element only.

Comment: No, // simply tells it to search for "*" from its relative position.  What // does compared to / is look for the item, skipping any node levels in between.  If it was //li[contains("boo")] it would look for the first list item containing "boo" down the line starting from where it's currently at.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already been hit by a search starting with // searching from the root of the document, not the element where I call the method. Should I use ./ or .// , perhaps? I'm not really sure yet how / vs // works.

Comment: Yes, you should. Use .// to find descendant element on all levels